How to read Flash ID (RDID) through SPI?
I try to read Flash ID (MX25L51245G) through SPI and my MCU is PIC32MX360F512L. According to the datasheet, the command should be 9F and receive C2 20 1A. But I always receive wrong ID data.
I tried to use Oscilloscope. I only have two probes, one is connected to CS# and another is connected to SI. In this situation, I receiced wrong ID data and when I Reset the debug mode, rxdata receiced another ID data. The data changes everytime.
Another situation is, my probes connected to SO and SI, now my rxdata can not receive anything in debug mode.
But I can see 9F on SI in two situation.
I use MP_LAB X IDE v6.20 to build my code.
Here is my main code and SPI initialize.
main code (I set the Breakpoin at a=0;)
#define Flash_ID_size    3
uint8_t rxdata[Flash_ID_size];
uint8_t flashIDbuffer[Flash_ID_size];
uint8_t a=1, b=1, c=1;

int main ( void )
{   SYS_Initialize ( NULL );
    uint8_t temp;
    uint8_t Flash_ID_command = 0x9F;
    nCS;  // Assert CS 
    //Flash ID
    SPI1BUF = Flash_ID_command;   //
    while (!SPI1STATbits.SPIRBF); //
    temp = SPI1BUF;  //
    temp = temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < Flash_ID_size; i++) {
           SPI1BUF = 0x00;
           while (!SPI1STATbits.SPIRBF); 
           rxdata[i] = SPI1BUF;  
    }
    DIS_nCS;  // Deassert CS 
    for (int i = 0; i < Flash_ID_size; i++) {
           flashIDbuffer[i] = rxdata[i];
    }
    b=0;
    a=0;
    return ( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

SPI1_Initialize
void SPI1_Initialize ( void )
{
    uint32_t rdata;

    /* Disable SPI1 Interrupts */
    IEC0CLR = 0x800000;
    IEC0CLR = 0x2000000;
    IEC0CLR = 0x1000000;

    /* STOP and Reset the SPI */
    SPI1CON = 0;

    /* Clear the Receiver buffer */
    rdata = SPI1BUF;
    rdata = rdata;

    /* Clear SPI1 Interrupt flags */
    IFS0CLR = 0x800000;
    IFS0CLR = 0x2000000;
    IFS0CLR = 0x1000000;
    

    /* Set the initial state of the SS1 pin */
    LATBSET = (1 << 2);  // Set SS1 high
    
    /* BAUD Rate register Setup */
    SPI1BRG = 39;

    /* CLear the Overflow */
    SPI1STATCLR = _SPI1STAT_SPIROV_MASK;
    TRISFbits.TRISF6 = 0;
    TRISFbits.TRISF7 = 1;
    TRISFbits.TRISF8 = 0;
    PORTFbits.RF6 = 0;
    PORTFbits.RF8 = 0;
    /*
    MSTEN = 1
    CKP = 0
    CKE = 0
    MODE<32,16> = 0
    */
    SPI1CONSET = (SPI1_CON_MODE_32_MODE_16 | SPI1_CON_CKE | SPI1_CON_CKP | SPI1_CON_MSTEN | SPI1_CON_SMP);

    /* Initialize global variables */
    spi1Obj.transferIsBusy = false;
    spi1Obj.callback = NULL;
    spi1Obj.txBuffer = NULL;
    spi1Obj.rxBuffer = NULL;
    spi1Obj.txSize = 0;
    spi1Obj.rxSize = 0;
    spi1Obj.txCount = 0;
    spi1Obj.rxCount = 0;
    spi1Obj.dummySize = 0;

    /* Enable SPI1 */
    SPI1CONSET = _SPI1CON_ON_MASK;
}

I think my SPI setting is wrong, but I don't know where is the problem? Is my SPI1CON wrong?
And why can probes cause the problem?
situation 1 CS#(Yellow line) and SI(Green line)
situation 2 SO(Yellow line) and SI(Green line)
some values at Breakpoint

You might check CLK and SI to verify if your CLK polarity is correct and if data is available at the correct edge of CLK.

@Gerhardh Thank you for your help. I switched to MPLAB IDE to build my code, and it works now. I can read the RDID in debug mode, and the value is correct. So I think there might be a difference in the toolsuite configuration. However, I’m still wondering what caused the problem when using MPLAB X IDE.

Did you do as I suggested? Maybe with MPLAB IDE you applied different SPI lines configuration.

Yes, I did. I have checked the clock. The SPI settings can be found in SPI1CON. The only difference is that when using MPLAB X IDE, my SPI1CON is set to 0xC220, whereas in MPLAB IDE, it is set to 0x8220. According to the PIC32 datasheet, bit 14 is unimplemented, read as ‘0’
